# How to set visibility of table row in PHP Office Word TemplateProcessor

Tags: php, phpword

I would like to conditionally display table row in predefined Ms Office Word file. The solution I am using currently only allows to manage display of whole block and so on the whole tables according to different combination of displayed data. I find this solution obscure. This is why I need conditionally display table row.

Current solution works with:

$$nameofdesiredkey

the conditionally shown content

nameofdesiredkay$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve that issue by workaround using another data table as result of dynamic values from pontential spread of values in the original table.

During my reserach idea of using multiple tables, using one dynamic data table list in one TD or just using $$variablestart variableend$$ and the start and end of each of nearest surrounding TDs seemed potent also.